# Interpret Ordinal Data on Likert Scale

Tags: regression, anova, mathematical-statistics

I am curious to know whether it is current practice in the statistical field to interpret and report data obtained on a Likert Scale (1: Strongly Agree to 5: Strongly Disagree), by finding the median value rather than averaging all the values for a particular item.
Please see [link here](http://achilleaskostoulas.com/2014/02/23/how-to-interpret-ordinal-data/)

My second question is how do we decide whether we should use 1: for Strongly Disagree rather than Strongly Agree such that:
1: Strongly Disagree    2:Disagree    3:undecided   4:Agree    5:Strongly Agree

1: Strongly Agree    2:Agree     3:undecided  4:Disagree     5:Strongly Disagree

Comment: Which end is 1 and which end is 5 is completely arbitrary. The conclusions should be the same. Select whatever goes with what's done in your field / literature.

Comment: Are you asking about estimating central tendency from your sample by taking the mean or median of responses to a single item from all respondents? @John: which end is 1 may be arbitrary on the part of the person who designs the scale, but it may affect conclusions. See [my answer here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96880/32036).

Comment: If we do an average of the number of responses x strongly agree (1) +...+number of responses x strong disagree (5) and conversely as above, we will get two different mean value. That is why I would like to know how do we decide whether we should use 1: for strongly disagree or 1: for strongly agree

Comment: Nick, there are differences in how they're presented to subjects if they see the numbers, that's true. This is about coding them post hoc...or so I thought. If it is about how it's presented to people doing the rating then my comment should be ignored.

Comment: Indeed, I am more interested to know how do we attribute the coding 1-5, to each Likert Type, post-data collection.

Comment: If you've already collected the data, how do you not already know whether 1 refers to strong agreement or disagreement?

Comment: Dear user39531, you asked 21 questions on this site and got for 16 at least one answer. But your vote count shows only ONE up vote and nothing else. Moreover, no answer has ever been accepted by you. Accepted answers and up votes are, however, sort of the daily meal for people offering their time in order to help people which only contribute by questions - people like you. Please appreciate answers with votes, accept them and make us smile.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have the one scale neither is current practice in the sense that it's the most common or best advice. It's probably better to use median and it would have to be a pretty special case to recommend mean. You should probably look up [ordinal regression](http://www.strath.ac.uk/aer/materials/5furtherquantitativeresearchdesignandanalysis/unit6/ordinalregression/), why it's used, and how to interpret it. Sometimes it helps to look at [R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_intro.pdf) or [SPSS](http://www.norusis.com/pdf/ASPC_v13.pdf) examples.